# dynamic KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME on kafka continer

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I use kafka in docker container.
One of the requirements is that the kafka will be available to a producer natively running on the host machine.
This is why I set the KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME to my host ip.

my docker-compose.yml looks like this:

```
version: '2'
services: 
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: 192.168.1.10
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "test:1:1"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERES: PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

and it works.

The problem is, I want to be able to use this docker-compose file also on other machines, and I don't know what their IP might be.

trying to change the ip into a name like 'kafka' caused it to be unavailable to the host machine (although still available from other containers).

Is there a way to use the host IP in the docker-compose file without "hardcoding" it (so that it will be a different IP address on different machines)?

Is there another way of addressing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

did you try using the property? It not recommend for production usage for whatever reason but it might work for you

> host.docker.internal

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/networking/#there-is-no-docker0-bridge-on-macos#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host

https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/networking/#there-is-no-docker0-bridge-on-windows#i-want-to-connect-from-a-container-to-a-service-on-the-host